# HPLIP Adding Support for HP DesignJet Z 2100

Tags: c++, linux, driver

I already asked the [same question in the HPLIP Forum](https://answers.launchpad.net/hplip/+question/272411) but got no answers.

I am a software developer and in the next project we need to print to the HP DesignJet Z 2100 using Linux.
I found this device on the unsupported list of HPLIP. I am quite experienced in C++ Windows/Max/Linux, but i never developed a driver.

Z 2100 is a proof pinter and we need proofing quality support for it.

Can anybody give me a hint how much work it would be to add support for the Z 2100?
Is at feasible at all - or is it just a question of parameterizing the printer?

Any hints appreciated.